# Invalid namespace prefix for xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I have the following xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:WasteTask xmlns:ns0="http://lcc/dm/waste/v1.0">
    <ns0:Identifiers>
        <ns0:Identifier>
            <ns1:Name xmlns:ns1="http://lcc/dm/common/v1.0">id</ns1:Name>
            <ns1:Value xmlns:ns1="http://lcc/dm/common/v1.0">242498</ns1:Value>
        </ns0:Identifier>
        <ns0:Identifier>
            <ns1:Name xmlns:ns1="http://lcc/dm/common/v1.0">ServiceCode</ns1:Name>
            <ns1:Value xmlns:ns1="http://lcc/dm/common/v1.0">SR00239776</ns1:Value>
        </ns0:Identifier>
        <ns0:Identifier>
            <ns1:Name xmlns:ns1="http://lcc/dm/common/v1.0">ExternalReference</ns1:Name>
            <ns1:Value xmlns:ns1="http://lcc/dm/common/v1.0">9024896</ns1:Value>
        </ns0:Identifier>
    </ns0:Identifiers>
</ns0:WasteTask>
```

I would like to select the *Value* node that has a sibling *Name* node containing "ExternalReference" i.e. select "9024896"

I've been using xml spy to run xpath. I hoped "//ns1:Value" would get me the *Value* nodes but it gives the error "Invalid namespace prefix".

The xpath works ok if I manually add the ns1 prefix declaration to the root node but I don't have the option of this in the actual application.

Is there another way to get the result I need with xpath? I have tried `"/*/*[local-name()='Value']"` but that returned no results.

Comment: `//*[local-name()='Value']` should do the job.

Comment: thank you - was just a typo! Do you want to add an answer and I'll mark as correct

Comment: `//*[local-name()='Value' and preceding-sibling::*[.="ExternalReference"]]` more applicable to your case

Comment: I think XML Spy supports XPath 2.0 so you should be able to do `//*:Value`

Answer (score 1):

With an XPath 2.0 engine (which I think XML Spy supports) you can do `//*:Value` to select any element with local name `Value`.